# Julia pandas - how to append dataframes together

Tags: pandas, dataframe, julia, pycall

Working with Julia 1.0
I have a large numbers of data frames which I read into Julia using pandas (read_csv) and I am looking for a way to append them all together into a single big data frame. For some reason the "append" function does not do the trick. A simplified example below:

```
using Pandas 

df = Pandas.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])

df2 = Pandas.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=['A', 'B'])

df[:append](df2)  #fails

df.append(df2)    #fails

df[:concat](df2)  #fails

vcat(df,df2)
```

The last step works but produces a 2 element Array with each element being a DataFrame

Any ideas on how to stack the two dataframes one under the other?

Comment: there's a julia Pandas now? _*facepalm_*

Comment: It's a wrapper to python pandas.

Comment: @crstnbr Is it faster to use the "native" Julia DataFrames package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work

```
julia> df = Pandas.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=[:A, :B])
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4


julia> df2 = Pandas.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=[:A, :B])
   A  B
0  5  6
1  7  8


julia> df.pyo[:append](df2, ignore_index = true )
PyObject    A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
3  7  8
```

Notes:

- I don't know if this is a Pandas thing or a julia 1.0 PyCall thing, but the object seems to need the .pyo field explicitly before calling a method. If you try `df[:append]` it will try to interpret this as if you're trying to index the `:append`: column. Try doing `df[:col3] = 3` to see what I mean
- There is a julia native DataFrames package. No need to use Pandas unless you have some weird "I have ready made code" issue. And even then you're probably just complicating things by using Pandas via a Python layer in Julia.

For reference, here's the equivalent in julia DataFrames:

```
julia> df  = DataFrames.DataFrame( [1:2, 3:4], [:A, :B]);
julia> df2 = DataFrames.DataFrame( [5:6, 7:8], [:A, :B]);
julia> append!(df, df2)
4×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ A │ B │
├─────┼───┼───┤
│ 1   │ 1 │ 3 │
│ 2   │ 2 │ 4 │
│ 3   │ 5 │ 7 │
│ 4   │ 6 │ 8 │
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The reason I am using Pandas is that the Julia native CSV.read is super slow to read the hundreds of csv files I need to read. And when I load pandas in Julia then Julia DataFrames has some sort of conflict and does not work. I would prefer to stay away from pandas but I haven't been able to use DataFrames in an efficient way.

Comment: @SilopS I'm genuinely curious.  What is the ratio of `DataFrame` contruction times between `Pandas.jl` and `CSV.jl`?  Have you tried [`CSVFiles.jl`](https://github.com/queryverse/CSVFiles.jl)?  How does it's speed compare?

Comment: CSV.jl took almost 2 minutes while the Julia code with Pandas read_csv took about 15 seconds. Big difference although I should revise my initial comment to say that initially I was not even able to read all the files with CSV.jl because it was crushing. I had to set "rows_for_type_detect=" to a large number to read all the files successfully. CSVFiles.jl does not load in my case because of "Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package JuliaDB". I am also not able to use JuliaDB with Julia 1.0 that I recently downloaded.

Comment: CSV.jl is coming up with a new version that will make it fast.  Perhaps you can try the simpler reader [CSVReader.jl](https://github.com/tk3369/CSVReader.jl) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you have a lot of dataframes, you can add them to a list. Then pd.concat the list, and take the header of the first file (assuming they all have the same header) as the header of the new dataframe. This will skip the first line in all your dataframes, so you dont have a bunch of header rows in there.

```
dfs = [df, df2]

df3 = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(dfs), columns=df.columns)
```